# Contradiction - Fourier series

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Consider for example $f(x) = -\frac{2}{\pi}x + 8\sin(\frac{x}{8})$
and $g(x) = -\frac{2}{\pi} + \cos(\frac{x}{8}).$

The Fourier series of $f(x)$ with a period of $4\pi$ is not odd, nor even, but it is the indefinite integral of $g(x)$ and the Fourier series of $g(x)$ with period $4\pi$ defined as $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is even. But how is that possible? The integral of an even function should be odd.

Comment: Are you saying $f(x)$ _is not_ odd?

Comment: I'm saying its Fourier series with a period of $4\pi$ repeated on all $\mathbb{R}$ is not odd but I don't understand why.

Comment: is your $f$ defined originally on $[-2\pi, 2\pi]$? Not something silly like zero to 4\pi? Can you provide your calculations of what the Fourier series of f and g are?

Comment: f is originally defined on $[0,4\pi]$. I don't want to calculate the Fourier series, but I only noticed a contradiction because $f(0)=f(4\pi)$ so if we repeat f(x) on all $\mathbb{R}$ we get an even function. That in contradiction to $f(x)$ being the indefinite integral of $g(x)$ which is not even or odd.

Comment: If you repeat $f$ periodically after and before $[0,4\pi]$, you don't get an even function.Numerically $f(1)\approx 0.36...$, but $f(-1)=f(4\pi-1) \approx 0.57$. You would get an odd function if you extended it from the interval $[-2\pi,2\pi]$.

Comment: @Ingix. You should make an answer with that. Show how the result depends on what interval is used, $[0,4\pi]$ or $[-2\pi,2\pi]$.

Answer (score 1):

Before we address your issue, let's take a closer look at two statements you make:

> The integral of an even function should be odd.

This is only true for the case where the offset is zero. To take a simple example, the constant function 1 is clearly even, but its integral

$$\int_0^x 1 \;\mathrm dx = x + C$$
is odd only if $C=0$.

> it is the indefinite integral of $g(x)$

**An** "indefinite integral of $g$" is just a function $F(x)$ such that $\int_a^b f(x) = F(b) - F(a)$. As usual, the family of such functions includes all those that differ by a constant. One of them in particular will be odd. However, the Fourier series actually tells you that it is the particular, definite integral that has a lower limit of zero.

---

Now, in your case, $f(x) = -\frac{2}{\pi}x + 8\sin(\frac{x}{8})$ is odd, and
$$\int_0^{x} g(t) \mathrm dt = \int_0^t \frac2\pi + \cos(t/8)\mathrm dt
= \frac2\pi x + 8 \sin(x/8) = f(x)$$
which is odd as desired --- but note that this integral is not indefinite.